# What do these PHP mbstring settings do?

Tags: php, character-encoding, multibyte, mbstring

I'm trying to figure out exactly what these php.ini settings do. What happens when they're set to different values? When are they necessary? When are they harmful?

- [mbstring.language](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mb-language.php)
- [mbstring.http_input](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mb-http-input.php)
- [mbstring.http_output](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mb-http-output.php)
- mbstring.encoding_translation

As usual, the [PHP manual](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mbstring.configuration.php) is less than helpful.

**EDIT**: Just to clarify, I understand how character encodings work, and I understand how PHP's multi-byte functions differ from their single-byte counterparts. I'm looking for specifics on what the above settings do.

**EDIT 2**: OK, it looks like they actually do provide more documentation than just the [page on runtime configuration](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mbstring.configuration.php), which just has one-line summaries. The first three of these have similarly-named functions, and there are more details on the pages that describe the function versions. I added links above.

**EDIT 3**: Adding a bounty. I'm looking for specific details on exactly what these settings do, especially the last three. What do they convert from and to, and when do they do it?

Comment: You're being sarcastic about the manual being less than helpful right?

Comment: I think it is very helpful, as a manual for PHP. You also need to understand HTTP and character encodings to make sense of these settings, though. And the PHP manual is not a manual for either of these things.

Comment: Re edit 2: I don't think the similarly-names functions are that helpful to your question. E.g., mb_language() implies that it only affects the encoding of email messages, whereas I get the impression that mbstring.language has a wider effect. And mb_http_input() just *detects* the encoding of data in the current HTTP request, which doesn't say anything about what the setting of mbstring.http_input does.

Answer (score 7):

You can change mbstring.language to whatever language you are using with. [(Source)](http://marc.info/?l=php-i18n&m=107060346828334&w=2)

language

```
; language for internal character representation.
mbstring.language = Neutral ; Set default language to neutral(UTF-8) (default)
mbstring.language = English
mbstring.language = Japanese
mbstring.language = Korean  ;For Korean market later
```

http_input

```
; http input encoding.
mbstring.http_input = pass
mbstring.http_input = auto
mbstring.http_input = UTF-8
mbstring.http_input = UTF-8, SJIS, EUC-JP
```

http_output

```
; http output encoding. mb_output_handler must be
; registered as output buffer to function
mbstring.http_output = pass
mbstring.http_output = UTF-8
```

encoding translation

```
; enable automatic encoding translation accoding to
; mbstring.internal_encoding setting. Input chars are
; converted to internal encoding by setting this to On.
; Note: Do _not_ use automatic encoding translation for
;       portable libs/applications.
mbstring.encoding_translation = On
```

Comment: mbstring.http_input and mbstring.http_output have been deprecated as of PHP 5.6.0. If you are on PHP >= 5.6.0, use the 'default_charset' directive instead.

Answer (score 3):

The point is to support different character set encodings.  There are a wide variety of encodings (ASCII, ANSI, UTF-8, etc) and each one has different character sets and number of bytes per character.  The settings your looking at specify default encodings for different PHP functions.

PHP supplies a number of functions that help you deal with these different encodings properly.  For an illustration, check out mb_strlen() vs strlen().

Short answer is, unless you're localizing your application's text, or communicating with systems with different encodings (your database included!), you probably don't need to worry about it.

Answer (score 2):

I think everything is explained by the demonstration in this example:

https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mb-internal-encoding.php#53265

Though it's not used in it, you can deduce the use of `mbstring.http_input`.